# Opencart Error trying to access Customers section of admin area

Tags: php, opencart

I have an opencart store setup and when I try to access the customers page from the admin area I receive the following error code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Error: Unknown column 'cg.name' in 'field list'<br />Error No: 1054<br />SELECT *, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS name, cg.name AS customer_group FROM oc_customer c LEFT JOIN oc_customer_group cg ON (c.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id) ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0,20' in /home/canad763/public_html/testshop/system/database/mysqli.php:41 Stack trace: #0 /home/canad763/public_html/testshop/system/library/db.php(20): DBMySQLi->query('SELECT *, CONCA...') #1 /home/canad763/public_html/testshop/admin/model/sale/customer.php(150): DB->query('SELECT *, CONCA...') #2 /home/canad763/public_html/testshop/admin/controller/sale/customer.php(408): ModelSaleCustomer->getCustomers(Array) #3 /home/canad763/public_html/testshop/admin/controller/sale/customer.php(12): ControllerSaleCustomer->getList() #4 [internal function]: ControllerSaleCustomer->index() #5 /home/canad763/public_html/testshop/system/engine/front.php(42): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6 /hom in /home/canad763/public_html/testshop/system/database/mysqli.php on line 41
```

Comment: Why don't you think, that reason of this problem is access to non-existent column 'cg.name'?

Comment: I added the coloum cg.name to the database, no change

Comment: Let's read your error message: "Unknown column 'cg.name' in 'field list'". Let's read part of your sql request: "...AS name, cg.name AS customer_group FROM oc_customer c...". I.e. you should'n add new column cg.name. You need to understand, why your sql request and your DB are not consistent. And only after it try to fix it.